# How long does it typically take for Chinese universities to accept or reject applicants?

Tags: graduate-admissions, china

How many days does it normally take to receive an admission letter after applying to a university in China?

I am a student from Bangladesh.

Comment: Days? Admissions processes normally last months. How long it takes for a given university varies from school to school.

Comment: @aeismail I think it is possible, that the OP didn't get an answer and he is "curious", what is happening.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. Are you applying for a graduate program? Which steps are involved and where are you at in the process? Depending on the program and application step it can take a week or over a month.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the programme of studies, the director that will see your application, plus whether there are additional requirements for your discipline, for example a portfolio. You might get lucky if you can email admissions again to ask which state your application is in, and how many stages you have before they conclude the process. Normally in a Chinese uni though they will ignore you until it is time to inform you.

Answer (score 1):

At Nankai, international students apply for a PhD or Master's program through the [International Student Service System](https://nankai.17gz.org/).  Applications are due around March, and the student starts in September (if accepted), so the answer to the question...

> How many days does it normally take to receive an admission letter after applying to a university in China?

...is "it depends on what time of the year you apply".  There's also three possible sub-questions:

- *How long does it take to get a letter of acceptance from your supervisor?*  As long as it takes them to decide they want that student, and for them to actually write it.
- *How long does it take for the university to accept/reject the student after they officially apply?*  Maybe a few months (assuming all the documents are in order).  Admin needs to decide who to recommend for government scholarships.
- *How long does it take the government (and hence the university) to respond to a student's scholarship application?*  Maybe 4 or 5 months.  It's a fairly long process.

The last two items don't apply (to the same extent) if the student is self funded.  I'm not sure about the circumstances for undergraduate applications, but I expect self-funded students are likely to be quickly accepted, and for those applications seeking scholarships to take months.

I'm not sure how typical this process is in China, but I guess it's standard practice.